# How to convert nested property list ( keys are not atoms ) to map in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have the following list

```
nl = 
[
  {"_id", "idhere"},
  {"App-Version", "version_here"},
  {"TX-ID", "tx-id-here"},
  {"Method", "method-here"},
  {"Body",
   {[
      {"Identification",
       [
         {"A", "A-Val"},
         {"B", "B-Val"},
         {"C", "C-Val"},
         {"D", "D-Val"}
       ]},
      {"CurrentTime", "2023-02-23T16:40:13+05:30"},
      {"Names", ["Name1", "Name2"]}
    ]}}
]
```

How to convert this to a nested map in Elixir ?

I tried using Map.new, but I am new to Elixir, can't get through.

Comment: When you tried Map.new it looked like `Map.new(nl)`? What happens when you try? Your "Body" looks a little funny--I often don't see tuples in Elixir with only one element, but as long as the key-value pair is 2 elements it should still convert into a map key and value fine.

Comment: Yes  Brett Beatty, you are right, this list is in fact generated from Erlang module ( private / legacy code ), as we see its a prop-list not a Keyword list.

Answer (score 1):

Got this [solution](https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-convert-nested-property-list-having-string-keys-to-elixir-nested-map/54093) from elixirforum (answered by andreaseriksson)

> ```
>   def transform([{_, _}|_] = list) do
>     Enum.reduce(list, %{}, fn {key, val}, map ->
>       Map.put(map, key, transform(val))
>     end)
>   end
>   def transform({[{_, _}|_] = list}), do: transform(list)
>
>   def transform(val), do: val
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The very similar but yet slightly different solution would be to use anonymous function.

```elixir
transformer = fn 
  [{_, _} | _] = list, f ->
    Map.new(list, fn {k, v} -> {k, f.(v, f)} end)
  {[{_, _} | _] = list}, f ->
    f.(list, f)
  other, _ -> other
end                        

transformer.(nl, transformer)
```